# Coordinate System to calculate the Coriolis Force of an object moving on the surface of a Planet like Earth

Tags: physics, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm somewhat lost and would like your help

If I understood correctly, the [Coriolis Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) happens when an object moves with a different rotation speed than the ground below it. For example, when an object moves North or South from the Equator, it will slide eastward because the rotation speed at the Equator is greater and slows down as you move toward the Poles. So the object will rotate faster East than the ground below it the more North or South it goes from the Equator.

I was wondering what kind of coordinate system should be used when dealing with an object on a planet like Earth, because the traditional 3D ccoordinates with origin at the Center of Earth make calculations a lot more difficult

Is it possible to have a coordinate System in such a way that calculating the Coriolis Force of an object is quick and straightforward instead of needing trigonometric functions to compute it with a Coordinate System at the Center of Earth ?

In other words, is there a Coordinate System that is more convenient to use for an object moving on the Surface of a Planet than this one

[image]

It doesn't seem to me that a Cylindrical or Spherical coordinate is better, but maybe you see it differently.

There isn't a lot of informations about the Coriolis Force on the Internet, especially applied Examples that show how to proceed for an object on the surface of a Planet like Earth, that's why I'm asking

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Feel free to comment if anything is unclear

Comment: It is an interesting question but it would surprise me when we have to reinvent the wheel. When I search for `coriolis earth` in physics stackexchange I get 449 results. This gives you a lot of stuff to do research. If you still want to start on your own I would recommend to calculate the Coriolis force on a flat disc first. I doubt that there are simpler coordinates than the polar ones.

Comment: How do you describe the velocity of the object moving on the surface of the planet? You will need to use some trigonometry, no matter what coordinate system you use.